# integration of dialogflow virtual agent with agent assist

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I've constructed a virtual agent in dialogflow cx and i  have set up the agent assist. How can I integrate them and provide management a demonstration? I only need to invoke the agent help when dialogflow encounters the human agent intent. Is it necessary to use a third-party programme, or is there an API for this?

I tried asking chatgpt but got no decent answers.